# Call GLKView render on request

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es-2.0, glkit, glkview

I create app using external renderer and how i can call redraw by request? For example, on Android I can do it using requestRenderer() and RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY render mode.

I have next code:

```
import UIKit
import GLKit
class RendererViewController: GLKViewController {

    var rendererView: GLKView!
    var filename: String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.rendererView = self.view as! GLKView
        self.rendererView.context = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)
        self.rendererView.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat.Format24
        self.setupGL()

    }

    func setupGL(){
        EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(self.rendererView.context)
         RendererBridge.initLLG()
        self.rendererView.bindDrawable()
        let wight = self.rendererView.drawableWidth
        let height = self.rendererView.drawableHeight
         RendererBridge.open(Int32(wight), hei: Int32(height), filepath: filename)
         RendererBridge.createRenderer(Int32(wight), hei: Int32(height))
    }



    deinit{
        if EAGLContext.currentContext() == self.rendererView.context{
            EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(nil)
        }
    }

    override func glkView(view: GLKView, drawInRect rect: CGRect) {
            RendererBridge.renderFrame()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by next steps:

1. Enable setNeedsDisplay for GLKView
2. Change GLKViewController to pause: `self.pause = true`
3. Call `self.view.setNeedsDisplay`